# How do I install the Scout-app?

Tags: compiler

I've downloaded [Scout-app](https://scout-app.io/). But I can't get it to work. The file Scout-app has the correct permission, and is executable. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

1. Unzip the file:   *unzip LIN64_Scout-App_2.18.16.zip*
2. cd Scout-App
3. ./scout-app

Will run without problems i do this at this moment.

Scout run in background if you close it will keep there until you kill. Maybe that is your problem.

best regards.

Comment: You might see Scout-App instead of scout-app

Answer (score 0):

It needs `sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4` to be run/installed on Linux distributions